# Get RowHeight of each row in UITableView Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview

is there a way to get the row height for each row in an `UITableView` in swift ? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you want to get the rowHeight? Did you using Auto Layout?

Comment: Ya i need the row height. I am using AutoLayout

Comment: Why do you want to get the rowHeight?

Comment: My row heights are dynamic. I need to alter the row height based on a condition. So I need the row height.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using self-sizing cells: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Swift 4:**

```
var height: CGFloat = 0
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    height += cell.bounds.height
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you are looking for. This assumes that **"Cell"** is the identifier of the given row, and **indexPath** is the index of the row in question.

```
let row = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! UITableViewCell

let height = row.bounds.height
```

Comment: but if i use autolayout? Because you way get me height what i set in storyboard

Answer (score 3):

Cells only exist when they are visible, and you have access to them through the table view's `visibleCells()` method.

```
for obj in tableView.visibleCells() {
    if let cell = obj as? UITableViewCell {
        let height = CGRectGetHeight( cell.bounds )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The functional way:

```
 let sum = tableView.visibleCells.map( { $0.bounds.height } ).reduce(0,+)
 print("Height:\(sum)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the cell for a certain `IndexPath` to calculate its bounds.

You can do it this way in any of the delegate functions of the `UITableView` :

```
let row = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
let cellHeight = (row?.bounds.height)!
let cellWidth = (row?.bounds.width)!
```